# How to send a notification email to a group when a form is submitted

Tags: activities, civirules, scheduled-reminders, formbuilder

I have a form with an individual (the logged in user), an organization (can be new or existing), and a grant (will be a new grant created on submission). The form works fine... I want to send an email to a group when the form is submitted that includes the values submitted in the form (mainly custom fields on the grant). I have tried adding an activity to the form and then using a scheduled reminder. This almost works except there doesn't seem to be any way to bring in the values submitted. I have tried using a CiviRule that triggers on the creation of a grant but that seems to not only have the issue of not bringing in the values but there does not seem to be any way to create an action that sends an email to a group or even a manually added list of contacts. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the front end you are using? We use Drupal and have an email handler connected to a webform that notifies the user submitting the form that the submission has been received and also sends an email to the staff group connected to the grant containing the values.

Comment: This is a Drupal 7 website with LOTS of webform and views functionality that we are trying to move from Drupal into CiviCRM in preparation for a move to Wordpress.